# PGN viewer for large databases?

Tags: database, pgn

What are some of the PGN viewers available for viewing/saving/editing a large number of chess games (more than 5k games)?

I am aware of chessbase. What are the other available options?

Comment: SCID and SCID vs PC. I prefer [SCID](https://scid.sourceforge.net/), it works fine for me with couple million games.

Comment: Can you add common functionality requests? E.g. some free PGN readers might hiccup on subvariants.